# Передать функцию в другую функцию

Tags: c#

Как сделать так чтобы функция `FillListStart` принимала в качестве аргумента функцию `TableRoTic`

```
private void FillListTar(List<List<double>> sortListArray1, List<List<double>> sortListArray2, string nameTar, bool flag)
{
    namesTar.Add(nameTar);
    dtTar.Add(new DataTable());
    tarIndex++;
    dtTar[tarIndex] = TableRoTic();
    DataRow newRow = null;
    if (flag == true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sortListArray1.ElementAt(0).Count; i++)
        {
            newRow = dtTar.ElementAt(tarIndex).NewRow();
            newRow["rho0"] = sortListArray1.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(i).ToString();
            newRow["tic"] = sortListArray2.ElementAt(1).ElementAt(i).ToString();
            dtTar.ElementAt(tarIndex).Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sortListArray1.ElementAt(0).Count; i++)
        {
            newRow = dtTar.ElementAt(tarIndex).NewRow();
            newRow["rho0"] = sortListArray1.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(i).ToString();
            newRow["tic"] = sortListArray2.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(i).ToString();
            dtTar.ElementAt(tarIndex).Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
    }
}

private DataTable TableRoTic()
{
    //создаём таблицу
    DataTable dtRoTic = new DataTable();
    //создаём три колонки
    //DataColumn a0 = new DataColumn("a0", typeof(Double));
    DataColumn ro = new DataColumn("rho0", typeof(String));
    DataColumn tic = new DataColumn("tic", typeof(String));

    dtRoTic.Columns.Add(ro);
    dtRoTic.Columns.Add(tic);
    return dtRoTic;
}
```

Comment: На будущее я бы рекомендовал Вам не задавать весь вопрос в заголовке. Это не очень хорошая практика. Заголовок должен быть информативным, но не надо весь вопрос туда впихивать. Кроме того, весь код в данной ситуации явно не нужен. Он лишь занимает место и отвлекает от сути вопроса. Отредактируйте, пожалуйста. [Тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) можно почитать о правилах оформления вопросов.

Comment: Вы задали довольно много вопросов - но ни на один не выбрали правильного ответа. Вам что, на них дают только неправильные ответы? Отметьте, пожалуйста, правильные ответы на свои вопросы такой зеленой галочкой.

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [делегатами](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173171.aspx).
Если вкратце - это как раз объект, содержащий в себе ссылку на метод.
Примерно так будет выглядеть код в Вашем случае:

```
// Объявляем тип делегата
delegate DataTable SomeDelegat();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Создаем  делегает, который ссылается на нужный метод
    SomeDelegat sd = new SomeDelegat(GetTable);

    // Вызываем метод с делегатом в качестве аргумента
    FillListTar(sd);
}

// Объявляем метод, на входе которому подается делегат
private void FillListTar(SomeDelegat sd)
{
    sd.Invoke(); // Выполнение метода делегата
}

private static DataTable TableRoTic()
{
    DataTable dtRoTic = new DataTable();
    // Какой-то нужный код
    return dtRoTic;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Два метода:

Определить свой делегат

```
delegate DataTable TableDelegate();
private void FillListTar(
    TableDelegate func,
    List<List<double>> sortListArray1,
    List<List<double>> sortListArray2,
    string nameTar,
    bool flag)
{
...
}
```

Либо, воспользоваться предопределенным делегатом `Func<TResult>`

```
private void FillListTar(
    Func<DataTable> func,
    List<List<double>> sortListArray1,
    List<List<double>> sortListArray2,
    string nameTar,
    bool flag)
{
...
}
```

Ну и вызов:

```
FillToStart(TableRoTic, ...);
```

Более подробно о `Func<TResult>` можно почитать [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)